# TypeError: Cannot read property 'question_set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to access data from a json that's returned from a server that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJbVC.png). However, when i try to console.log question_set (i'm trying to access it so i can render the data), i get a TypeError. Any ideas on how i can render question_set and answer_set?

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class tryout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        message: '',
        quiz_taker: null,
        question: null,
        answer: null,
        
      }
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      
      const token = this.props.token;
      const API_URL = "/api/quizzes/testquiz";
      const configs = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Token ${token}`}
      }
  
      fetch(API_URL, configs)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status > 400) {
          return this.setState(() => ({message: 'Something went wrong'}))
        } return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState(() => ({data: data,
          message: 'Success'}))
      })
     
    }
  
    render() {
      const details = this.state.data.quiz.question_set[0].label
      console.log(details);
      
      return (
        <div>test</div>
        
      )
      
     }
   }
   export default connect((state) => ({token: state.auth.token}))(tryout);
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is run _after_ the initial render. So during the initial render, inside the `render` method, `this.state.data.quiz` will be undefined. You could solve the problem using an `if` statement to check whether `this.state.data.quiz` is defined or not. You could also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `this.state.data?.quiz.question_set[0].label`

Comment: well 2 problems: 1. why is your component starts with lowercase letter? 2. why you define call back function instead of updater on setState method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it takes some time to fetch the data from the API.

You can use this to get rid of the error.

```
const details = this.state.data?.quiz?.question_set[0]?.label
```

This "?" proceeds only if the value is defined.

Comment: btw `?.` is called an optional chaining operator and it was added in es2020.